# Rails custom route for user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to have the URL of a users profile in this format: mydomain.com/username

I have started to implement it in the user model:

user.rb

```
before_create :create_permalink
.
.
def to_param
  permalink
end
.
.
private

  def create_permalink
    self.permalink = username.downcase
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
end
```

routes.rb

```
match "/:permalink", to: "users#show", via: 'get'
```

When I visit mydomain.com/username a user profile does display but when I do it through the `user_path(current_user)` link, I get this error

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

and the URL is mydomain.com/user/username, which I don't want.

How do I edit the default rails route and edit user route to be in the format I want?

routes.rb:

```
Code::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users,  except: [:edit, :show]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root 'pages#home'

  match '/help',    to: 'pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: 'get'

  match '/signup',          to: 'users#new',        via: 'get'
  match '/signin',          to: 'sessions#new',     via: 'get'
  match '/signout',         to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'

  get '/:permalink',      to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
  get '/:permalink/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit_user'
end
```

After removing just the `as: 'user'` line and left `as: 'edit_user'` I ran `bundle exec rake routes | grep -i "user"`:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
     user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)          users#new
          GET    /:permalink(.:format)      users#show
edit_user GET    /:permalink/edit(.:format) users#edit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use helper methods, give names to the routes:

```
get '/:permalink',      to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get '/:permalink/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit_user'
```

it's cleaner, you also all the advantages of named routes

EDIT: your resource is creating a "user" named route for the update action

```
user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
```

You have two options to fix it:

1- The easiest (i would recomend this): use another name for those two new routes:

```
get '/:permalink',      to: 'users#show', as: 'custom_user'
get '/:permalink/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'custom_edit_user'
```

now you call those actions as "custom_user_path" and "custom_edit_user_path", no conflict

2- The more complicated: user another name for the resource

```
resource :users, except: [:edit, :show], as: 'old_users'
...
...
get '/:permalink',      to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get '/:permalink/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit_user'
```

This way you can use user_path and edit_user_path but all the other "user*" routes will have to change to "old_user*_path", like: instead of "new_user_path" you would have to use "new_old_user_path".

I recommend you to use the 1st options, check all your code and use "custom_user_path" or "custom_edit_user_path" and you will be done

Comment: But doing so gives me this long error: `Invalid route name, already in use: 'user' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with 'resources' as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created`

Comment: I have also added `resources :users, except: [:show, :edit]` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: do "bundle exec rake routes" before adding the as: options and see what action is creating the "user" route and add that action to the except instead of :show, maybe it's something else

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what your asking, I ran `bundle exec rake routes` and the user show is `user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show` how would I change that?

Comment: add the "except: [:show, :edit]" part and see what routes are created with bundle exec rake routes. Also, have you restarted your server after updating the routes?

Comment: Doing so removes edit_user and user path. Also, after restarting the server, putting `as: 'edit_user'` works for the second one but `as: 'user'` doesn't work

Comment: @Tim, That last error is saying you defined it twice. You need to delete one the user lines. You may still have that 'match user' line in there and then pasted this post's 'get user line. And if i'm not mistaken, you shouldn't use match, use get like the user recommended instead.

Comment: copy your current routes.rb

Comment: I have added my routes.rb file, but now I get this error: `undefined method 'edit_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x50fba10>:0x345c330>`

Comment: run "bundle exec rake routes | grep -i 'user'", you should have a named route for edit_user, if not you need to check something else, routes.rb looks fine to me, have you restarted the server? where is "edit_user_path" being called? maybe you are missing something in that context and not on the routes.

Comment: I just got rid of `as: 'user'` because it wouldn't let me run it otherwise, I have added the results to the original question

Comment: Ok, the problem was the update action using the user named route, check my update to my answer

Comment: @Abram all sorted no need. arieljuod thanks for that, it works fine now